# JSON with '-' in key reading in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have this JSON

```
{
"data":{
  "string-x": "21",
  "string-y": "110"
}
}
```

the string x and y is coordinates

I just want to call the coodinates by

`data.string-x` and `data.string-y` but I got this error

ReferenceError: x is not defined

what am I missing? it seems javascript treat data.string-x like equation not regular node call.

could anyone help me.

Comment: `data['string-y']` ?

Comment: It's better to use camelCase stringX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.string-x` is treated as subtraction expression, equal to `data.string - x`

so change your code to `data["string-x"]`